# Узнать прокручен ли скролл до элемента с id?

Tags: jquery

На странице есть блоки в которые динамически добавлены id например bl_1, bl_2, bl_3 и так далее каждому блоку.
Как при скролинге узнать, дошёл ли он до элемента?

```
$(".supermenu").each(function () {
        $(this).attr("id", "s_" + i);
        var iconClass = [];
        iconClass[1] = "";

        var m = $(this).text();
        var listElement = '<li><a class="scroll" href="#s_' + i + '">' + m + '</a></li>';

        $(".topmenu ul").append(listElement);
        i++;

    });
```

Comment: Доскролил значит

Comment: Это не конструктивно. Не такого: `if (element.is(':доскролил'))`. Что значит _доскролил_? Элемент **полностью** на экране? Элемент **хотя бы на один пиксель по высоте** на экране? Может, вообще какой-то третий вариант?

Comment: Да хотя бы просто доскроллил до элемента.
Не ужели так непонятно?

Comment: На вопрос _или, или, или_ отвечать "да" несколько странно, но попробую угадать: речь про _хотя бы на один пиксель по высоте_? Чем точнее вы опишите желаемый результат, тем больше шансов, что вам быстро и правильно помогут. А ещё в вопросе имеет смысл добавить HTML-код и JS-код динамического добавления элементов.

Comment: А что непонятного в фразе _нужно покрасить вот этот забор_? Очевидно же: есть забор, нужно его покрасить. Только вот когда вам покрасят забор не тем типом краски и не тем цветом, вы, возможно, задумаетесь над тем, что стоило точно описывать что вы хотите увидеть на заборе.

Comment: >> Узнать прокручен ли скролл до элемента с id?
Ну разве же неясно что просто прокручен до него, ни пиксель ни шмиксель, да по барабану хоть три пикселя. Просто когда элемент появился на экране ПРИ скроллинге, то что-то делать. О Господи!

Comment: [jquery.appear](https://github.com/morr/jquery.appear). Вместо того, чтобы изображать из себя мученника, которого просто завалили уточняющими вопросами можно было отредактировать пост, внеся озвученные требования к решению.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Решил проблему следующим образом:

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
    s_top = $("body").scrollTop();
    yes = $("#id").offset().top;
    if(s_top > yes){
        console.log("Yes");
    }
});
```

Comment: Не забудьте отметить ответ как принятый.

Comment: Кстати, вы всё ещё можете отметить ответ галочкой )